# Why mockito dothrow is not throwing exception

Tags: mockito

I have a void method, lets's say in "SomeClass"

```
public void someMethod(SomeArg arg) throws SomeException{
```

Where, SomeException is of type RuntimeException

```
SomeException extends RuntimeException
```

In my test case, I am writing :

```
SomeArg someArg =new SomeArg ();
someArg .setId(1234);
Mockito.doThrow(new SomeException ()). when(someClass).someMethod(someArg );
```

And I expect exception

```
@Test(expected=SomeException .class)
```

But surprisingly, it's not throwing the exception. Am I missing some stuff ?

Comment: Hmm, what I noticed that if toString is not proper or there are insufficient arguments for equals method, Mockito do not throw exception. In first case, toString was throwing NPTR, and in yet other use case equality does not had enough information to complete (one of ID was missing) .. why does throws behavior of mockito fails due to this? If it had failed some equality or some operation on these objects, i could have understand .. But I have just started with mockito, so not sure about its philosophies.

Comment: So did you manage to solve your problem finally? Could you post the SomeArg implementation?

Comment: Yes, Mockito was not giving the trace properly .. as mentioned in comment, tostring and equals were throwing exception which was not being propagated by mockito properly -all it would say Exception -but the trace was missing. Fixing NPTR in modules below solved it..

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Yes, Mockito was not giving the trace properly .. as mentioned in comment, tostring and equals were throwing exception which was not being propagated by mockito properly -all it would say Exception -but the trace was missing. Fixing NPTR in modules below solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  In my instance, I had mocked the class under test using powermock (as the class under test was an abstract class) and I had not set up that the real method should be invoked during the test.  This prevented doThrow from being invoked.

If "SomeClass" is being mocked, then you need to make sure that you add the line the set up of your test:

```
doCallRealMethod().when(SomeClass).someMethod(someArg);
```